# Value selection from 2d array in numpy using a 2d coordinate array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

In numpy, arrays can be indexed by other arrays that contain the array indices:

```py
>>> x
array([ 4, 16, 64])
>>> inx
array([1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2])
>>> x[inx]
array([16, 16,  4, 64,  4, 64, 64,  4, 16,  4, 64, 16, 16, 16, 64, 16,  4,
       64, 64, 64])
```

Now suppose `x` was of shape `(3,3)`, and `inx` of shape `(20, 2)` (containing in each row integral 2-d coordinate pairs), can I get an array like `x[inx]`, i.e. of shape `(20,)` that contains for each row the corresponding entry of `x`.

Comment: `x[inx[:,0], inx[:,1]]` - use each column of `inx` as a index for each dimension.  `x[i,j]` is the same as `x[(i,j)]`.

Comment: Each dimension has to have its own indexing array.  `x[idx]` would give a (20,2,3) because it only indexes the first dimension.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can use advanced indexing to achieve this, i.e.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
inx = rng.integers(0, 3, (20, 2))
print(x[inx[:,0], inx[:,1]])  # array([2, 4, 5, 2, 0, 5, 8, 8, 3, 7, 4, 2, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 8, 1])
```

You can do the same thing but with less code by first transposing the array and then unpacking it, i.e.

```py
print(x[*inx.T]) # array([2, 4, 5, 2, 0, 5, 8, 8, 3, 7, 4, 2, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 8, 1])
```

We need to transpose it first because unpacking will split the rows so we transpose `inx` to be `(2, 20)` such that the unpacking passes the row and column indices individually.